# froalaEditor.file.beforeUpload Event not firing

Tags: wysiwyg, froala, angular-cli-v7

I'm attempting implement the custom file upload feature of the Angular Froala WYSIWYS Editor. I've pasted my configuration options below.

In the console, I can see that both the `froalaEditor.file.beforeUpload` and `froalaEditor.file.inserted` events are triggered, but no HTTP action of any kind is fired and neither the `froalaEditor.file.uploaded` nor the `froalaEditor.file.error` events are triggered.

Does any know why Froala is not attempting to POST to my fileUploadUrl?

```
options: Object = {
fileUploadUrl: 'https://localhost:5001/api/file',
events: {
  'froalaEditor.file.beforeUpload': function (e: any, editor: any, files: any) {
    console.log('BEFORE UPLOAD', e, editor, files, files[0]);
  },
  'froalaEditor.file.inserted': function (e, editor, $file, response) {
    console.log('INSERTED', e, editor, $file, response);
  },
  'froalaEditor.file.uploaded': function (e, editor, response) {
    console.log('UPLOADED', e, editor, response);
  },
  'froalaEditor.file.error': function (e, editor, error, response) {
    console.log('ERROR', e, editor, error, response);
  },
}}
```

Version Info:

Angular CLI: 7.3.0

angular-froala-wysiwyg: "^2.9.1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) 
While using command froalaEditor.file.beforeUpload and froalaEditor.file.inserted, if you wish to see the HTTP response on your URL kindly have the following property included -

```
fileUploadMethod: 'POST'
```

2)
Events can be triggered using -

```
console.log("Custom Message")
```

Refer JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/dyt52pqk/2/